# How to Redirect Domain

Tags: url, redirect, dns, cross-domain

I have two domains like one is flexha.com and second is flexha.co.uk.I want that whenever user search flexha.com.User must go to flexha.co.uk.How can I do that? what is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that flexha.co.uk uses Apache / Nginx to serve content, you can point the DNS at this same server and within web serwer config redirect.

Other than this, some DNS providers offer redirection or something like AWS S3 based redirection.